# Search query with uft-8 characters in UWP and Sqlite

Tags: c#, utf-8, uwp, sqlite-net

For a same search query

```
select * 
from Dictionary 
where vi_Name like '%quả táo%'
```

When I run the query in SQLite, it returns a record, but when I copy the same query to uwp and run it, I get "No record found". If I switch to English letter (a-zA-Z), the query searches fine, but no result for utf-8 characters like à á... What could be the different?

Here is my code:

```
public class Dictionary
{
     public string en_Name { get; set; }
     public string vi_Name { get; set; }
}

SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    string path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "dictionary.db");
    conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
}

private void btnFind_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Dictionary> result = conn.Query<Dictionary>(@"select * from Dictionary where vi_Name like '%quả táo%'");

    if(result .Count > 0)
        txtEqual.Text = result[0].en_Name.ToString();
}
```

Comment: *"What could be the different?"* - Your query is encoded using UTF-16LE, but you opened the database with a default encoding of UTF-8.

Comment: i dont know if i get this right: when you run the utf-16le query in sqlite utf-8 encoded database, it's auto convert utf16-utf8 but when you run that same query in UWP app, nothing change?

Comment: I don't know this, but the SQLite command line utility could identify the default encoding and proceed accordingly (either by opening the database using the respective call to [open](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html), or compiling the SQL statement using [prepare](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html)). There's probably also a way to change the default encoding at runtime, using SQLite-specific pragmas. Your code, on the other hand, doesn't attempt to do anything special, to deal with a UTF-8 encoded database.